# Connect to google api

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-gradle-plugin

I have prograammed for a couple of years now, but never made an Android app before, therefore the build.gradle and manifest are new to me.

The app I am trying to make is an app that tests kids on the multiplication table. The app worked perfectly, but then I tried to add the function to log into Google and use the achivements in Google Play, but I can't seem to connect to Google api.

I have tried to follow this tutorial: [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), but with no luck.
I get an ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, resolution=null} whenever I try to connect.
Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nilsen.anders.multiplication"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.andste569.multiplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.andste569.multiplication.MainActivityMultipl"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity_multipl"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is my gradle.build. Do not know for sure if minyfy should be enabled or not, but I've tried both. The buildscript is just copied from an example, I do not know what it does.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nilsen.anders.oblig_4"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I belive my problem is in the manifest or gradle, and not in the activity_main, because I followed the tutorial quite precisely, but I will post my code as well.

```
package com.example.andste569.multiplication;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ErrorDialogFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.nilsen.anders.multiplication.R;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

// Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
// Unique tag for the error dialog fragment
private static final String DIALOG_ERROR = "dialog_error";
// Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
private boolean mResolvingError = false;
private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";


private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.andste569.oblig_4.MESSAGE";
public final static String EXTRA_MULTIPLIER = "com.example.andste569.oblig_4.MULTIPLIER";
public final static int MINMULTIPLIER = 4;
public final static int MAXMULTIPLIER = 12;
public final static int SNDRMULTIPLIER =10;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private int progress;
private final String LOGTAG ="debug_mul";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,Integer.toString(checkPlayServices()));

// Create a GoogleApiClient instance
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    //Setup seekbar.
    seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(MAXMULTIPLIER-MINMULTIPLIER);
    seekBar.setProgress(SNDRMULTIPLIER-MINMULTIPLIER);

    final TextView textViewSeekValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSeekValue);
    final TextView textViewSeekMin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSeekMin);
    final TextView textViewSeekMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSeekMax);

    progress=SNDRMULTIPLIER;
    // Initialize the textviews.
    textViewSeekValue.setText(Integer.toString(seekBar.getProgress()+MINMULTIPLIER));
    textViewSeekMin.setText(Integer.toString(MINMULTIPLIER));
    textViewSeekMax.setText(Integer.toString(MAXMULTIPLIER));

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progressValue+MINMULTIPLIER;
            textViewSeekValue.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changing seekbar's progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);
}

//TODO: Handle connection failures

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Connected to Google Play services!
    // The good stuff goes here.
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"onconnected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection has been interrupted.
    // Disable any UI components that depend on Google APIs
    // until onConnected() is called.
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"onconnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // This callback is important for handling errors that
    // may occur while attempting to connect with Google.
    //
    // More about this in the next section.
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"onconnectionFailed");
    if (mResolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mResolvingError = true;
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
        showErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode());
        mResolvingError = true;
        Log.wtf(LOGTAG,result.toString());
    }
}

/* Creates a dialog for an error message */
private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    // Create a fragment for the error dialog
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
    // Pass the error that should be displayed
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR, errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "errordialog");
}

private int checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    return resultCode;
}

/* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
public void onDialogDismissed() {
    mResolvingError = false;
}
/* A fragment to display an error dialog */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
        int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
        return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mResolvingError) {  // more about this later
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"onstart");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i("debug","oncreateOptionMenu");
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
}

public void MultiplicationButton(View view){
    multiplicationWindow("mul");
}

public void DivisionButton (View view){
    multiplicationWindow("div");
}

private void multiplicationWindow(String operation){
    Log.wtf("debug","Opening window");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivityMultipl.class);
    EditText editTextName =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,name);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MULTIPLIER,progress);
    intent.setAction(operation);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.wtf("debug","Opening window2");
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){

}

public void SignIn (View view){
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"connectingbuttonStart");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.wtf(LOGTAG,"connectingbuttonEND");
}
}
```

Comment: i think you are using too often Log.wtf and the system took offence :-)

Comment: @pskink Why would it get offended by "What a Terrible Failure"? ;P

Comment: @jamp sure: "What a Terrible Failure", everybody knows what they and you mean...

Comment: Hehe, well, I've tried everything else, just might as well change the "wtf" :)

Comment: UpDate: when running the signed APK I the error message: Unknown issue with google play services.